# Getting error on heroku cedar stack when running 'heroku run bash' from cli

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to just get into bash on Heroku Cedar stack and I'm getting the following:

```
$ heroku run bash

Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.1
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:87:in `fixup': undefined method `force_encoding' for "\e[01;34m~\e[00m \e[01;32m$ \e[00m":String (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:63:in `start'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:46:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:46:in `start'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:118:in `rendezvous_session'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:104:in `run_attached'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:167:in `send'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:167:in `run'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:28
```

Any ideas of what is causing this error or how to remedy it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What's the heroku command line version? Try upgrading it, whether it's the toolbet or the rubygem.